# Dice game with class

Tags: python, class

I'm going crazy about an exercise. I have to make a dice game, where we are asked how many players will play the game, how many rounds will be played, and how many dice are used. Then, in the first round the dice are rolled; if a player can guess the number of a die, he gets a point for each die he guesses correctly; if he doesn't get any dice right, that's minus one point only. Then, I have to show each player their score.

But the real problem is that I have to use classes and objects and that's the real problem.

I would appreciate no comments that say this is some regular thing to do because I'm not very good with classes and objects and he could comment an idea of a program like this it would be great. Thank you very much

```
import random

class Dice:

    def __init__(self,num_players,num_rounds,num_dices):
        self.num_players=num_players
        self.num_rounds=num_rounds
        self.num_dices=num_dices

    def roll(self):
        self.number=random.randint(1,6)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)

def main():

    nPlayers=int(input('How many players? '))
    nRounds=int(input('How many rounds? '))
    nDices=int(input('How many dices will be used? '))
    game=Dice(nPlayers, nRounds, nDices)
    for i in range(nRounds):
        for j in range(nPlayers):
            game.roll()
            guess=int(input('Try guessing the number player'+str(j)+str(' ')))
main()
```

Comment: Have you tried becoming good with classes and objects by reading the docs and practicing? We won't do your homework here or write the exam for you. We expect an honest attempt, including some code, and then we can help you whenever a specific problems arises.

Comment: but i did try, my program is in the question but im still confused about it, and im just trying to figure what is right with the program and what is wrong with it. im no lazy guy...

Comment: *" what is wrong with it."* Nothing wrong with it. You have to continue to implement *he gets a point* and *show each player their score.*

Comment: OK, that's at least an attempt! Now you need to tell us what's wrong with your code.

Comment: ok so the problem is to make that condition of if he gets the number of the dice right, he gets one point for each dice  he got right, and minus one point if didnt get any dice right, but the real problem is to save each amount of points for each player. i tought it would be a good idea to use a dictionary that presents the players and each amount of points

Comment: Thats a possible solution, but you *"have to use classes"*!

Comment: so youre saying i have to make a function inside the class for the dictionary? i think it could work

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record I managed to get the program the way I wanted. Just gonna post it if anyone has the same exercise and need help. Thanks guys!!

Here it is

import random

class Dice:

```
def __init__(self,num_players,num_rounds,num_dices):
    self.num_players=num_players
    self.num_rounds=num_rounds
    self.num_dices=num_dices
    self.value=random.randint(1,6)
    self.dic={}
    self.list=[]

def game(self):
    for i in range(self.num_rounds):
        for k in range(self.num_dices):
            self.value=random.randint(1,6)
            self.list.append(self.value)
        for j in range(self.num_players):
            guess=int(input('Try guessing the number player'+str(j)+str(' ')))
            if(guess not in self.list):
                if(j in self.dic.keys()):
                    self.dic[j]-=1
                else:
                    self.dic[j]=-1
            elif(guess in self.list):
                n=self.list.count(guess)
                if(j in self.dic.keys()):
                    self.dic[j]+=n
                else:
                    self.dic[j]=n

        print(self.list)
        self.list.clear()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.dic)
```

def main():

```
nPlayers=int(input('How many players? '))
nRounds=int(input('How many rounds? '))
nDices=int(input('How many dices will be used? '))
game=Dice(nPlayers, nRounds, nDices)
game.game()
print(game)
```

main()